# Mysql latin characters issue in java

Tags: java, mysql, character-encoding, resultset

I have a table named 'tasks' with columns taskid, taskname and description.

Description column has values with latin characters like 'ô' .

```
SELECT    cast(`taskname` as binary)
FROM  `tasks` TC_1
WHERE  (cast(`description` as binary)  IN ( 'Impôrtant'  ))
```

When I run a query like this in MySQL, I'm getting the result but when I run the same query using java `executequery` method, the resultset is empty.

I have tried the below query too:

```
SELECT    cast(`taskname` as binary)
FROM  `tasks` TC_1
WHERE  (cast(`description` as binary)  IN (cast( 'Impôrtant' as binary )))
```

but facing the same issue.

I think the issue is related to character set.

My database character set is 'latin1'.

Note: ignore syntax errors

Comment: are you sure the executequery method doesn't alter the text?  You can check the actual query in the query log. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html

Comment: `ô` can be encoded in latin1 hex `F4` or in utf8 as `C3B4`.  We cannot answer your question without knowing which hex is in the table and is in `Impôrtant`.  Any answer given may be wrong and may make things worse.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the escape sequence for the character, for the character you gave it'll be \u00F4. If you want to find escape codes for other characters you can use https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html.